# Parse PFQuery bug with geoPoint constraint

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am doing a pretty straightforward PFQuery. I want to get any objects where the specific key I'm entering exists, and the object is within 2 km of user location. However, this query returns all objects within 2 km, but doesn't filter out anything to only return objects where that key exists. I checked and the key ("T(objectIDs[0])") contains the information I think it does. Additionally, I have tried this in a compound query where I am doing a different key in each query. This query works as expected and returns objects within 2 km AND only where the key exists. Have any of you seen behavior like this? Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
let singleQuery = PFQuery(className: locationTagsClassNameConstant)
                singleQuery.whereKeyExists("T\(objectIDs[0])")
                singleQuery.whereKey(geoPointColumnNameConstant, nearGeoPoint: userGeo, withinKilometers: 2)

                singleQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
                   if error == nil {
                      var dataToExtract:Array<AnyObject> = []
                      if let objects = objects {

                         for activity in objects {
                            dataToExtract.append(activity)
                         }
                         complete(result: dataToExtract)
                      }
                   } else {
                      // Log details of the failure
                      print("Error++++: \(error!)")
                   }
                })
```

Comment: What about that backslash `\` in `("T\(objectIDs[0])")` as compared to the `("T(objectIDs[0])") ` which you said works?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is just a string I'm plugging in the spot `\(objectIDs[0])` depending on the objectID.